# ClosedXml HeatMap / Conditional formatting in Excel document

Tags: c#, .net, closedxml

I'm using OpenXml **( switched to ClosedXml )**, I'm trying create a Heatmap in code, like the below sample.  How can I achieve that ?

I haven't found any snippets to make this happen.

[image]

Comment: Is using ClosedXml an option? ClosedXml makes OpenXml easy to create such a file.

Comment: what have you tried? what issues are you running in to?

Comment: I was looking at conditional formatting, not sure how to make it work though.

Comment: I might switch to ClosedXML, looks like it's found in their examples - https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML.Examples/ConditionalFormatting/ConditionalFormatting.cs

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Stefan, this is easy using ClosedXml

https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/develop/ClosedXML.Examples/ConditionalFormatting/ConditionalFormatting.cs

```
    public void Create(String filePath)
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var ws = workbook.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");

        ws.FirstCell().SetValue(1)
            .CellBelow().SetValue(1)
            .CellBelow().SetValue(2)
            .CellBelow().SetValue(3);

        ws.RangeUsed().AddConditionalFormat().ColorScale()
            .LowestValue(XLColor.Red)
            .Midpoint(XLCFContentType.Percent, "50", XLColor.Yellow)
            .HighestValue(XLColor.Green);

        workbook.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
```